# how to detect change in sql database without making http requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to make a realtime website I used Ajax Http calls using setInterval(), it works well but it make the website too slow. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: hahah . I have problem, what is answer?

Comment: one word, `websockets`

Comment: How to use websockets for php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use any of the several techniques collectively called "[comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)", such as never-ending frames, web sockets, etc. There are libraries that abstract things for you, such as [SocketIO](http://socket.io/).

Comment: I want to make a website like facebook which load posts without making ajax Calls

Comment: @eWeb.comoj.com: I doubt they do, I expect they use ajax calls to load posts. They may well use various comet techniques to know that there are new posts to load, hence the answer above.

Comment: I have seen on facebook in ( Inspect Element->Network tab ) but there are no any calls. But in my site there are coming new calls each second which make my site slow.